# Need to store a uint in a variable before putting it in the agrument af a function call

Tags: c++

I was trying to read an integer stored in a file as 4 bytes.
To read it, I implemented the function `readInt()` which will read the next four bytes of a char array and transform it to an integer.

```
//The whole thing is in a class
char *content;
uint32_t index = 0;

uint32_t nextInt() {
    const uint32_t i = index;
    index += 4;
    return ((u_char) content[i]) << 24 | ((u_char) content[i + 1]) << 16 | ((u_char) content[i + 2]) << 8 |
           ((u_char) content[i + 3]);
}
```

I used this function lots of time without any issues until today: I found a bug:
When I use the function like below, it works perfectly like I want to:

```
uint32_t count = nextInt();
geometry.setup(count, nextInt());
```

But if I change the code a little bit to make it looking like below, it just stop working.

```
geometry.setup(nextInt(), nextInt());
```

I get an `out of memory` exception. This exception is caused because I create an array but I get a wrong argument.
Things will be better if I show you how `geometry.setup()` works:

```
void Geometry::setup(uint32_t newVertexCount, uint32_t newIndexCount) {
    std::cout << newVertexCount << std::endl;
    std::cout << newIndexCount << std::endl;

    vertexCount = newVertexCount;
    indexCount = newIndexCount;
    vertices = new Vertex[vertexCount];//out-of-memory exception here. vertexCount=1065353216
    indices = new uint16_t[indexCount];
}
```

In the first case, `newVertexCount` is `36` and `newIndexCount` is `24` (which are the expected results).

But in the second case, the values are `1065353216` and `1052770304`. Why?

Note that `count` is not used anywhere else.

Any idea?

Comment: That is too much of a code puzzle for my taste. Could you make a [mre] to demonstrate the things you are describing?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupes: You cannot depend on the side affects of function calls as parameters to a function.  The ordering is unspecified.

Comment: In this call `geometry.setup(nextInt(), nextInt());`, the two `nextInt()` can be called in [any order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) since C++17. Pre-C++17 this caused undefined behavior.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But they anyway won't be executed at the same time, right?

Comment: In C++17 they won't.